# MVC validator errors disappear by the time control is given to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a simple model `FilesModel` for updating a string `Description` and the boolean value of a checkbox `Archived` for a few (already uploaded) files, and `FilesModel` has a validator `FilesModelValidator` that gets run when this data is posted. This validator does nothing more than check that each file has a description. I know that it runs and correctly returns an error for empty descriptions based on my debugging so far.

However, when control is given to the Action method in the Controller, ModelState is different from what I expect. There are no errors on the description fields, but there is one error for each checkbox that is checked: "The value 'on' is not valid for Archived."

Validation of this sort works just fine in other areas of the site, so I'm sure there's some minute thing I'm overlooking. Any suggestions as to why this may be happening and how to fix it?

**Validator**

```
public FilesModelValidator()
{
    RuleFor(f => f.Files)
        .Must(AllHaveADescription).WithMessage("Must have a description");
}

public static bool AllHaveADescription(Files files)
{
    // This is run on postback, and returns false when any Description is empty
    return files.All(f => f.Description != null && f.Description.Length > 0);
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Update(FilesModel model)
{
    // At this point, ModelState contains an error for each checked checkbox
    // and no errors for empty descriptions
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Save
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: How do you have your validator wired up?  Property attributes or just some entity-based logic?

Comment: Attributes. The following is an attribute on the `FilesModel` class: `[Validator(typeof(FilesModelValidator))]`

Comment: Could it be simply running the validation twice and dropping your exiting errors?  (using a custom model binder maybe?)  Also, I vaguely remember something about registering the data annotations (?)  .. but that would be giving you problems with all of them and you're using more than one right?

Comment: I am using a custom model binder. I will take a look into that.

Comment: I found that my custom model binder is running and returning a correct version of the model, then my validator is running and correctly erroring on empty description. Something is happening *after* my validator is run that is causing problems.

Comment: Tangent : Hey, would you mind doing a (blog?) post on how you're doing that validation?  Mine's a bit more manual (not attribute based) but I'm curious how that all works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out the checkbox thing was the entire problem. I found a solution to this problem elsewhere in our code, so I used it. It seems kind of hacky, but it works.

The idea is that you need to make sure that the checkbox's value is `true` and not "on". So do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" value="true" />
```

Then add a hidden input with the same id with its value as `false` immediately after the checkbox:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myCheckbox" value="false" />
```

When a checkbox is not checked, the checkbox value does not get posted back to the server. So when the postback occurs, the server sees `myCheckbox=false` which is exactly what we would want in this case. When the checkbox *is* checked, *both* input values get posted to the server. But the server uses only the first value (which is the value of the checkbox itself, since we put it before the hidden field). So the server sees `myCheckbox=true`.

Comment: Thanks for this ingenious workaround. However, having two elements with the same id attribute is invalid markup. Instead, you should give them different IDs but add the attribute name="myCheckbox" to both elements. This achieves the same result, but with valid markup.

Comment: @RichardFawcett - I am a believer in valid markup, so thank you for that!

Comment: Slight nitpick. You don't need the hidden input at all. If your input is bound to a bool then it will simply result in false. The modelstate will also be valid. All you need is the input to have the name of the value that it binds to, and `value="true"`. Id's are only used client side and have nothing to do with model binding.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following in the view rather than manually creating the checkbox:

```
Html.CheckBox("FieldName")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for items in a drop down that were linked to an Enum.  I had stripped out the default value and so when someone didn't select something I got an error.

So, having said that, I think your problem might be kinda linked in that the binder is looking for a true/false when your model is expeting a yes/no or vice versa.

Two ways around this might be to change your view to be True/False or, and this is what I did, to write my own ModelBinder which does the conversion from Yes to True.

I hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: I have a custom model binder which correctly interprets the value of the checkbox, and the boolean on the model is correctly set to true or false. It appears that it's not the model binding that is at fault, but a validator that I'm not seeing.